# How to create a Docker container with an img file

Tags: docker

I have an img file for a Darts game application running on a Raspberry. This application can run as a server and I would like to host it in a Docker Container.

I have converted the img into a `tar.gz` file and have imported it into Docker (under Synology).
I am trying to launch it but it always fails because of the execution command.

First thing, is it possible to run into Docker this `tar.gz` that is coming from an img file ?
What should I use as an execution command since it is mandatory ?

I have also tried to launch the container with `docker-compose` command with this file :

```
version: '2'

networks:
    default:
        external:
             name: mymacvlan

services:
    pydarts_server:
        container_name: raspydarts
        image: raspydarts:202154
        privileged: true
        pid: "host"
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        command: sh /pydarts/pydarts_server.sh
        hostname: raspydarts_server
        mac_address: a0:ca:ab:cd:ef:01
        ports:
          - "5005:5005/tcp"
          - "5006:5006/tcp"
          - "3022:22/tcp"
          - "3080:80/tcp"          
        networks:
             default:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.1.244
        volumes:
             - "/volume1/docker/raspydarts/.pydarts/:/home/pi/.pydarts"
             - "/volume1/docker/raspydarts/pydarts/:/pydarts"
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
             - PUID=1024
             - PGID=100
             - TZ=Europe/Paris
             -  PATH=/home/user/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

I tried `/bin/bash`, `/bin/sh`, none of those commands is working.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Where did the "img file" originally come from?  When you say you converted it into a tar file and imported it, what steps exactly did that entail?  What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, the img comes from a facebook group dedicated to RaspyDarts.
The img works fine when I burn it on an SD card for my raspberry.

To convert the img into a tar file, I simply used this software : https://filestar.com/skills/img/convert-img-to-tar-gz

When I try to launch the docker image, I get an "OCI runtime create failed" error because of my  execution command. I don't know what to set as exec command in the setup of the container.

Comment: A Docker container isn't a hardware emulator or a virtual machine.  It usually runs a single process, and you'd usually have a source file called a Dockerfile with a `CMD` directive that states what that process should be.  I don't think you'd be able to successfully import a bootable disk image into a container in the general case.